# Can Javaagent be given a file path of Aws S3?

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aop, javaagents

I have a java application that I **submit as a spark job from EC2 instance to Aws Emr**. In the application, I have implemented **aspect-oriented programming(aop)** for logging. To make aop work I need to specify **aspectweaver.jar** while submitting the job. This works fine if I specify the jar present in EMR cluster. But I want to specify the jar from S3 path. Below is the code snippet:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn-cluster 
--driver-java-options \"-Djavaagent=s3://fintellix-la/jobs/aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar\" 
--jars s3://bucket-name/jars/* --driver-cores 1 --driver-memory 20G 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true 
--class project.main.index s3://bucket-name/jobs/projectbatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Above code does not give any errors but aop is not initiated.

Similarly I tried different options for --driver-java-options,

```
--driver-java-options -javaagent=s3://bucket-name/jobs/aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar
--driver-java-options -Djavaagent=s3://bucket-name/jobs/aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar
```

These gave errors like:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar
```

**Note- I am also reading other jars and main jar from S3. Which it is able to read and works fine. But unable to read in javaagent.**

I thank you very much for helping me